# Initial selected Item in an UITabBar without a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I set the ***default*** selected UITabBarItem in an UITabBar that is within an UIView, not an UITabBarController?

Just to clarify, the UIView does implement the  protocol and the didSelectItem method works. At run-time, the tabbar works and the tabbaritems selected when the user touches them. My problem is setting the default selected item.

If i use [myTabbar setSelectedItem] within the didSelectItem method it works. But outside of it, it doesn't (for example, in the viewDidLoad method of my UIView).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to post some sample code. I just ran a quick test in `-viewDidLoad`:

```
UITabBarItem *about = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"About.png"] tag:0];
NSArray *tabBarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:about,nil];
[tabBar setItems:tabBarItems animated:NO];
[tabBar setSelectedItem:about];
[tabBarItems release];
[about release];
```

which worked fine, or at least worked as I expected.

Comment: It works now. For some reason the connection between the tabbar in the xib and the variable was lost. Still, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for your approatch, but I still have a problem that the didSelectedItem is not called when I select the item with setSelectedItem. Any Idea?

actually, I did use it a little bit different:

`[tabbar setSelectedItem:[tabbar.items objectAtIndex:0]];`

finally I solved it this way....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 UITabBarItem *item = [myTabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
 [self.myTabBar setSelectedItem:item];
 if(tab1Exam == nil){
  self.tab1Exam = [[CurExam alloc] initWithNibName:@"CurExam" bundle:nil];
 [self.view insertSubview:tab1Exam.view belowSubview:myTabBar];
 if (currentViewController != nil)
  [currentViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
 currentViewController = tab1Exam;
 }
}
```